# Problem with read text file in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

Hello How to read below txt file ?

[image]

Comment: It's not a fixed width file, it's a CSV file? use `pd.read_csv` with `sep=','`

Comment: great! thnk you !

Answer (score 0):

Your file appears to be a csv, not a fwf. Use `pd.read_csv`.